# sed syntax for replace with reserved characters

Tags: batch-file, sed, find, exec

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to search through a text file and insert a new line after the search is found.

I want to add

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
```

After

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Only if the line after `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` is blank.

My plan is to use it in a `find` command to batch update lots of wp-config.php files.

My attempt without escaping characters is:

```
find . -name wp-config.php -exec sed 'define('WP_DEBUG', false);
i\ define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');' {}
```

Comment: What reserved character is the title talking about?

Comment: I assumed, since the script wasn't working, brackets, quotes and perhaps semicolons were causing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a regular expression match as a condition (or "address") in sed, you must wrap it in slashes:

```
sed "/define('WP_DEBUG', false);/idefine('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');"
```

Note that I used double quotes so the single quotes can be used inside without breaking the expression.

However, if the string should be replaced only if the following line is empty, I would switch to Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/^$/define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');/ if $previous eq "define('WP_DEBUG', false);\n";
$previous = $_;
```

Testing it:

```
echo "define('WP_DEBUG', false);
non empty line.
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

previous line is empty

What about last line?
define('WP_DEBUG', false);" | 1.pl
```

Output:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
non empty line.
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
previous line is empty

What about last line?
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Comment: Excellent, the Perl script works well, however I'm at a loss as to how to overwrite the file once passed through the script?

Comment: @chrismcb: You can add the `-i~` switch to perl to change the file in place while saving a backup.

Comment: Excellent, the script works - and in its entirety of my use: `find . -name wp-config.php -exec wp_ftp_check.sh {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
perl -pe 'if($f==1 && /^$/){print "mydata";$f=0;}if(/define\(\047WP_DEBUG\047\, false\)\;/ ) {$f=1}' your_file
```

you can add what ever you want in `mydata` part.

tested below with your data:

File

```
> cat temp
a
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
b
c
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

bjwebfwke
```

Execution

```
> perl -pe 'if($f==1 && /^$/){print "define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');";$f=0;}if(/define\(\047WP_DEBUG\047\, false\)\;/ ) {$f=1}' temp
a
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
b
c
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define(FS_METHOD, ftpext);
bjwebfwke
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed "N;s/define('WP_DEBUG', false);\n$/&define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');/;P;D" file
```